# Протухает авторизация телеграм

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

Попробовал отправлять сообщения в телеграм при помощи TLSharp ([хабр](https://habr.com/post/277079/), [гитхаб](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)).

Ну, вариант рабочий. Однако есть следующая проблема: после коннекта к серверу нужно пройти аутентификацию, используя hash и code - и этот code приходит на телефон.

Этот code достаточно быстро протухает (в api точно не указано ([раз](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth), [два](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.signIn)), но где-то меньше часа кажется прошло) и если я даже сохраню этот код, то со временем всё равно получу исключение:

> InvalidOperationException: PHONE_CODE_EXPIRED

А это значит, нужно снова лезть (руками!) в телефон и в отладчике менять на лету значение переменной. Да-да, автор так и [советует](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp):

```
var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("<user_number>");
var code = "<code_from_telegram>"; // you can change code in debugger

var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("<user_number>", hash, code);
```

Только вот это совсем не production ready. :(

Кто может порекомендовать хороший способ автоматизировать этот процесс?

На ум приходит только вариант получения какого-то долгоиграющего ([судя по](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode) api самого телеграмма - этот code можно получить либо в СМС на телефон, либо в приложение телеграмма) кода (на месяц хотя бы), но я не нашёл в api варианта получить такой токен (да и сомневаюсь, что по соображениям безопасности они будут выдаваться).

Comment: Клиент служба на телефоне :) целый комплекс получится. И вариант приделать ГСМ ЮСБ донгл к компьютеру, и завязываться на него, с получением кода. Там правда апи смс отвратительно организованно, но как вариант.

Comment: @NewView OMG, что ж так сложно-то... (( Такие способы подходят скорее для энтерпрайза, а вот чтобы я сам себе в домашнем приложении кидал уведомления в телегу -- как-то чересчур. Похоже, не скоро я реализую себе такую фичу или поищу более другой клиент, чем телеграм для подобных целей. В принципе, можно и в вебе просить ввести код в отдельное поле на веб-форме, но как-то это... не особо удобно. Официальный клиент не требует же ввода кода каждый час.

Comment: Ну если личное, тогда скидывать код пришедший по смс приложению, можно что-то лёгкое написать, для экспорта смс и передачи по udp например. Останется только слушателя в программе на ПК завести.. Можно даже все смс броадкастом по домашней сети рассылать :) кому надо, тот поймает..

Comment: Извините если глупость скажу (мне не приходилось работать с TLSharp), но чисто по логике: Родной клиент телеги ведь не просит у вас код из СМС каждый час.Он его просит только один раз, при первом запуске. Значит, вероятно, вы что-то делаете не так. Ну и автор пишет `When user is authenticated, TLSharp creates special file called session.dat. In this file TLSharp store all information needed for user session. So you need to authenticate user every time the session.dat file is corrupted or removed.` Может при повторном запуске уже не надо запрашивать код, а работать сразу после `ConnectAsync()`?

Comment: И еще. Если вам всего лишь надо отправлять себе уведомления, то вполне можно воспользоваться [BotApi](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot). Не знаю всех нюансов вашей задачи, но может он лучше подойдёт. Ему и авторизация через телефон не требуется.

Answer (score 4):

Моё предположение в комментариях оказалось верным. Проходить авторизацию нужно только при первом подключении. В дальнейшем TLSharp сохраняет все нужные данные в файл session.dat и использует его при последующих подключениях. Повторная авторизация может потребоваться в двух случаях:

- Файл session.dat был удалён/повреждён
- Пользователь закрыл сессию (причем, мог сделать это воспользовавшись другим клиентом)

Ниже приведу работающий пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp.Core;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            // Следующие два значения нужно получить на https://my.telegram.org/apps
            var apiId = 123456;
            var apiHash = "foo";

            // Номер телефона пользователя
            var phoneNum = "+75551234567";

            var client = new TelegramClient(apiId, apiHash);
            await client.ConnectAsync();

            var isAuth = client.IsUserAuthorized();
            Console.WriteLine($"Файл авторизации существует: {isAuth}");

            if (!isAuth) // Если не найден файл session.dat, то пытаемся авторизоваться
            {
                TLUser user;
                try
                {
                    var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(phoneNum);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите код из SMS:");
                    var code = Console.ReadLine();

                    try
                    {
                        user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(phoneNum, hash, code);
                    }
                    catch (CloudPasswordNeededException)
                    {
                        // На данном аккаунте включена двухфакторная авторизация
                        var passwordSettings = await client.GetPasswordSetting();
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите пароль:");
                        var passwordStr = Console.ReadLine();

                        user = await client.MakeAuthWithPasswordAsync(passwordSettings, passwordStr);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Пользователь '{user?.FirstName}' авторизован");

                isAuth = client.IsUserAuthorized();
                Console.WriteLine($"Файл авторизации существует: {isAuth}");
            }

            try
            {
                // В качестве демонстрации работы узнаем количество контактов у пользователя
                var contacts = await client.GetContactsAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"У вас {contacts.Users.Count} контактов");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.Message == "AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED")
            {
                // Файл session.dat существует, но для сервера эта сессия уже мертва
                Console.WriteLine("Пользователь воспользовался другим устройством чтобы закрыть текущую сессию.");
                Console.WriteLine("Удалите файл session.dat и повторите попытку.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мгм. Я ещё тогда хотел сказать, что у меня на месте файл session.dat - и я не знаю, как закрыть сессию (я ничего не делал в официальном клиенте), поэтому вряд ли делал. Но спасибо, что решили разобраться в вопросе - я наверное подыму заново свой код и попробую посмотреть, что происходит у меня в коде более тщательно. Вполне возможно, что вы просто отправляли запросы постоянно, а не сделали перерыв на час - или вообще не дождались конца срока действия кода. К сожалению, я не вижу как посмотреть это время (в api телеграмма оно есть, но tlsharp не отдаёт), а было бы интересно.

Comment: Возможно я вас неправильно слышу, но код из СМС вообще больше не нужен после того как единожды был введён. В session.dat, как я понимаю, хранится не он, а некая криптографическая магия (не вникал), которая является достаточной для подключения без всяких СМС. После авторизации я ждал пару часов и после этого приведенная программа успешно отработала (не заходя в if). Но в любом случае, даже если я вас не так понял, то может кто-то попадёт сюда из гугла и ответ ему пригодится.

Comment: Разумеется, поэтому я и поставил плюс, а не галку. Возможно, что у меня что-то иначе сделано - и это повод для других вопросов, а пока спасибо за уже простое упоминание того факта, что у кого-то работает после первого же получения авторизации - мне этот факт очень пригодится в моих дальнейших раскопках. Я же вообще думал, что нужно будет gsm модуль с симкой ставить и доп. софт писать.