# Отправка сообщений пользователю по номеру телефона в Telegramm с помощью Telegram.Bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, telegram, asp.net-web-api

Приложение asp.net core 5.0. Установил библиотеку Telegram.Bot, создал в телеге свой чат-бот.

В приложение создал объект TelegramBotClient:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MessageController> _logger;
        private static  string _token { get; set; } = "1956785959:AAH1648648646464546464PVgK5hxmlk";
        private static TelegramBotClient telegramBotClient;

public MessageController(ILogger<MessageController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            telegramBotClient = new TelegramBotClient(_token);
        }

[HttpPost("sendMessage")]
        public async Task SendMessage([FromBody] Message message)
        {
            telegramBotClient.StartReceiving();

            // test your api configured correctly
            //var me = await telegramBotClient.GetMeAsync();
            //Console.WriteLine($"{me.Username} started");

        }
    }
```

Не могу понять как мне отправить личное сообщение пользователю по номеру телефона (пользователь не знает о моем чат-боте) с помощью данной библиотеки, везде описывается как отвечать уже написавшему пользователю.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью данной библиотеки?

Если нельзя с помощью этой библиотеки, то с помощью какой можно?

Comment: Если пользователь не знает о чат-боте - никак, вы же понимаете, что телеграм by design запретил эту возможность, чтобы тонны спама не вываливалось на незнакомых людей. Как только в названии библиотеки вы видите слово "бот" - можете смело пропускать.

Comment: @AK, понял, спасибо

Comment: [Вот эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/928403/213987) вроде обещает что можно отправлять, но у меня с ней были проблемы и я в итоге плюнул ибо под мою задачу хватило бота.

Comment: @AK, значит через бота буду пытаться. Скажите  какой мне проект C# нужно создать, чтобы можно было его запустить на хостинге он слушал бота и пересылал запросы другому моему web-сервису (C# asp.net core тоже)?

Comment: Обычная dll'ка netstandard2, приложение на asp.net core 3.1 на пятой пока не пробовал - хостер не имеет поддержки .net5, до этого на 2.x работало без проблем несколько лет.

Comment: @AK, если приложение на asp.net core 3.1, то это web-api? Но там же работа идет когда есть запрос к контроллеру, а как заставить его работать все время?